# Getting different field label while accessing it in apex component

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, fields

here the sObjectType is of `Account` type

```
 Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

 for (String fName: fieldMap.keySet()) 
    System.debug('Field Name '+ fName + ' Label '  +fieldMap.get(fName).getDescribe().getLabel() );
```

in `Salesforce` account object field name for phone is `Phone` and lable is also `Phone` but when I try to access it using above method it shows field name as `Phone` and label as `Account Phone`

*screenshot of my logs*

[image]

Not sure why it is happening this way

*screenshot of account from `Salesforce`*

[image]

While accessing it using `Tooling API` it shows the correct label

> SELECT
>   EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName,FieldDefinition.DataType,FieldDefinition.Label,FieldDefinition.QualifiedApiName
>   FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName IN
>   ('Account')

*screenshot of result fetched using Tooling API*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case is that for import wizard you use as much accurate labels as possible, so the label shown by `fieldMap.get(fName).getDescribe().getLabel()` is guarantee that when fields are mapping they will not overlap.

What I mean, is that you have Phone field label in Lead, Account, Contact and so on.

Here is the documentation that matches `.getLabel()` with actual label that is shown in UI.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=field_mapping_for_other_data_sources_and_organization_import.htm&type=5

> Account Phone -> Account: Phone

Comment: But don't you think it may confuse user as we are using standard field labels so that they don't think that `Phone` and `Account Phone` are two different fields. I guess alternate way is to use `Tooling API` what you think

Comment: Yes, sure, if it suits you. I've just explained why there is the difference.